# How to constraint from the center in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I'm new to Auto Layouts and the concept of constraints. I'm currently trying to create a single view app with two buttons:

[image: constraints]

The buttons must meet the criteria shown in the image above. I can do everything except the two constraints where the buttons have to be a 30 above and 30 below, as it resizes the entire button to the point that one overlaps the other.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm not doing the constraints programmatically, but rather on the storyboard. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide details of the constraints you are adding?

Comment: @Paulw11 is the image not enough? What else must i provide?

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is; I added the constraints that you have indicated and it looks correct, aside from the buttons not being the same heights, but you haven't specified that as a requirement.  One thing I note is that you may have your 30/-30 the wrong way around depending on what the first item in the constraint is.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you please post what constraints you have used? That's my main issue here.

Comment: I have exactly the constraints you have listed, except I have -30 between the bottom of B1 and the centre of the superview and 30 between the top of B2 and the centre of the superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is to ensure that after setting alignment constraints both from the center, to select the following option of either the "bottom" or the "top" depending on how you want it:

[image]

This ensures that there is no "overlapping" caused.

Answer (score 0):

Try put both of them in a view, add constraint between them 60px height, then make the view center of the superview, leading and trailing 20px, optional 50 from top and 150 from bottom, you should get the desired result.